# How to use AS in QueryBuilder?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How can I use `AS` in the following join statement:

```php
User::join('role_user', 'id', '=', 'user_id')
        ->join('roles', 'role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->where('roles.name', 'teacher')
        ->get('roles.name AS roleName') // <-- invalid AS usage just for demonstration
```

As already mentioned, the problem is, that `user.name` **overrides** `role.name`. How can I modify the above query, so that `role.name` is **renamed** to `role_name` and is preserved in the results?

Comment: You answered your own question.

Comment: @curious_coder I know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using `AS` in `select(...)` statement:

```php
User::join('role_user', 'id', '=', 'user_id')
        ->join('roles', 'role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->where('roles.name', 'teacher')
        ->select('*', 'roles.name AS roleName') // <--
        ->get()
```

As mentioned, key part in the query is the select statement:

```php
// select all of the columns while renaming 'roles.name' one
...->select('*', 'roles.name AS roleName')
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorporate it in select statement

```
User::select('roles.name AS roleName')
        ->join('role_user', 'id', '=', 'user_id')
        ->join('roles', 'role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->where('roles.name', 'teacher')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but this query selects **only**  `roleName`

Comment: I thought you only needed to use roles.name as roleName so I posted this. Anyways you got the solution.